# How can I set an element's background-color in an HTML file?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set an element's background-color without a CSS file? Just using an HTML file?

In this case, I have a div I want to style. But I could want to style other elements in the future.

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: .2;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;" style="background-color:red;">text</div>
```

Comment: You could use inline styles, but I don't know why you'd want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using **two style attributes** on a single div element, which is invalid:

```
<div style="height:100px;" style="background-color:red;">text</div>
```

Instead, use (if using different CSS styles, separate them by `;` like below)

```
<div style="height:100px;background:red;">text</div>
```

You *can* use inline CSS *in the HTML*, or by using the `bgColor` attribute.

You can use the `bgColor` attribute, like `bgColor="#6B6B6B"`, in the `body` element to change the background-color of `<body>`.

> The HTML **[`bgcolor`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-bgcolor-attribute/)** attribute is used to set the **background colo**r of an HTML element. Bgcolor is one of those attributes that has become **deprecated** with the implementation of **Cascading Style Sheets**.

It Supports tags like

> `<body>`,`<marquee>`, `<table>`, `<tbody>`,`<td>`,`<tfoot>`,`<th>`,`<thead>`,`<tr>`

**DEMO USING bgColor**:

```html
<body bgColor="#6B6B6B">
  <div style="height:100px;background:red;">text</div>
</body>
```

**DEMO WITHOUT USING bgColor**:

```html
<body style="background:#6B6B6B">
  <div style="height:100px;background:red;">text</div>
</body>
```

NOTE:

You can add background color by using [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) and [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) property in CSS

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: .2;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.mydiv {
    background:red;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="mydiv">text</div>
```

Comment: @Yummi if you want to do that with only html, then check this out: `<div style="background:red;padding:5px;color:white;text-align:center;">text</div>`

Answer (score 1):

**Working Code**

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: .2;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;background-color:red">text</div>
```

Your syntax was broken for inline styles. You were specifying styles two times.